# Bit reversal in opencl kernel

Tags: opencl, fft

Hi can someone explain to me the OpenCL algorithm to perform bit reversal on complex numbers. I have checked the bit hacks page and on the GPU none of them work.

Thanks for answering

Comment: do you have a starting point to work with? a single-threaded version which works for you perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "none of them work" exactly ? You know that bit reversal in the context of FFTs is about reversing the bits in an *index*, not in the complex values themselves, right ?

Comment: Oh right thanks I completely forgot about that!!! I will try that. I thought I was missing something, thanks Paul for pointing me in right direction!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD Documents an example of this using OpenCL:

http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/OpenCLOptimizationCaseStudy-PartI.aspx

Comment: I Love AMD - Page Not Found